# Solicito gente con acceso a escuelas o colegios de educación media y superior

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

La meta para este sitio es de convertirnos en el mejor recurso gratuito para desarrolladores de habla hispana. Necesitamos seguir creciendo y ofreciendo el más alto nivel de ayuda posible con buenas preguntas y respuestas.  Para poder lograr esto, es necesario atraer a la mas grande cantidad de usuarios que se interesen no solo en consumir la información presentada sino que también busquen maneras de ayudar al público por medio de contribuciones a nuestro contenido. Tengo en mente una idea que podemos discutir como comunidad para lograr esta meta.

**Embajadores educacionales de SOes**

Este sitio es de ayuda no solo par el profesional sino que también para el estudiante de los lenguajes de código. Tenemos entre nosotros personas que puedan ayudar con la incrementación de las preguntas.  Lo que hace falta es anunciar que SOes esta vivo y activo.

Me gustaría platicar sobre cuales serian las mejores maneras de evangelizar nuestra causa a los estudiantes.  Busco ideas, gente con conexiones, y oportunidades para poder hacer correr la voz en estos canales.

Tengo en mente el preparar a algunos de nosotros para poder formar eventos, dar clases, regalar premios, etc. en los colegios o escuelas para poder llamar más atención a la comunidad de SOes y la ayuda que podemos proporcionar. Platiquemos más sobre esta idea. Veamos que se puede crear.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Aunque la foto demuestra a niños, la idea es para estudiantes mayores (universidades y colegios).  *Disculpen la confusión.*

Comment: ¿Esto está restringido solamente a instituciones de educación primaria y secundaria o también incluiría educación superior (Universidades)?

Comment: @dwarandae Yo solo pensaba en universidades

Comment: @jasilva igual yo, si el proyecto tiene esta amplitud yo podría colaborar en la Universidad en la que estudio.

Comment: Yo diría universidades y también instituto/bachillerato/prepa (donde ya empiezan a tener clases de tecnología/programación), pero dejaría primaria y secundaria fuera.

Comment: Y aún así, iría con pies de plomo. Si no se enfoca bien, SOes acabaría lleno de preguntas del tipo "haced mi tarea de programación por mí"

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si, por eso lo platicamos primero.  Este sitio no se convertirá en aula de tutoría o ayuda de tareas solamente.

Comment: Me llama mucho la atención que no haya más participación en esta pregunta ¿Se ha discutido este tema en otros espacios?

Comment: @Rubén lo hemos platicado en el chat pero falta tener más voces e ideas. Tal vez un webcast para discutir esto estaría bien...

Comment: Gracias @JuanM. El problema con el chat y los webcast es que implica que coincidamos en tiempo tanto horario como de "attention span". Sugiero que algunos de los participantes tome el rol de cronista o documentador y nos comparta un resumen o en el caso del chat podría ser un link.

Comment: ¿En qué quedó esto? ¿Es posible colaborar aún?

Comment: @dwarandae estamos planificando esto todavía - ¿te interesa participar?

Comment: @JuanM Sí señor, ¿qué es posible hacer?

Comment: @JuanM: ¿Cómo va este tema? ¿sigue abierto?

Answer (score 4):

### Aprende el arte de programar

Me parece una excelente idea, y en mi caso, yo creo que voy adelantado ya en este aspecto, estoy dando clases a mi hermano menor el cual esta en ultimo año de secundaria; la forma en que lo logre, fue utilizando algo, que la mayoría de profesores en todos lados ha pedido pasar a sus estudiantes, y eso es la **INSPIRACIÓN**.

Los puntos por los cuales yo me baso serian los siguientes:

1. Educar acerca de informática a las personas que nos rodean, partiendo desde nuestro hogar, hasta aquellos interesados.
2. Hacerse con recursos básicos (Tablero, marcadores, borradores, entre otros.) que nos ayuden a brindar tal conocimiento.
3. Inspirar a los jóvenes, a través de experiencias personales, o enseñarles casos puntuales de lo magnifico que es aprender este **ARTE**.
4. Se podría crear especies de academias con la intención de enseñar a los jóvenes, y mejorar aquellos que lo deseen, para esto se debe visitar las escuelas y universidades.

En mi experiencia, mi hermano juega juegos tipo **MMORPG**, y el un día me empezó a preguntar, que tan difícil era hacer un juego, que se debía aprender, que herramientas, entonces yo recordé algo que había visto, y se lo pase para que lo viera, el documental llamado ***Indie Game***, lo vio y ahora tomo las historias de las personas que vio como inspiración, y pues allí va aprendiendo día a día.

En mi caso, también busco la forma de al menos, tener un poco de recursos, para para dar clases, y visitar a los colegios.

Comment: Felicidades en tener la iniciativa de empezar a educar a los jóvenes sobre esta importante area de tecnología. Lo que proponemos aquí es atraer a todos los que podamos a unirse para encontrar respuestas a sus preguntas  mientras aprenden con otros miembros.  Necesitamos gente que pueda promover este recurso gratuito.  Estamos pensando on los recursos necesarios para promover esto.  ¡Seguimos en contacto!

Comment: En eso estamos,

Answer (score 3):

> Creo que le punto mas importante en las universidades , podrias montar un canal en youtube presentado problemas clasicos de la programacion como factoriales , vectores , arboles , persistencias en los lenguajes mas conocidos con eso ganarias muchos seguidores para futuros eventos

Comment: excelente sugerencia, ¡gracias!

Comment: ¿Te interesaría formular algunos de estos videos? Podemos grabar unos videos y ponerlos en nuestro canal de YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtuOuRfJHaReTPEPf0RTMVg

Comment: Lo haria con gusto , pero tienes algun prgrama para grabar pantalla que sea gratiuto?

Comment: te mando un email con detalles. :)

Comment: A daniel1945_o@hotmail.com o daniel72584@gmail.com porfa

Comment: ¿recibiste el correo?

Answer (score 3):

## Orientación Vocacional

Una oportunidad temprana es que los embajadores educacionales participen en eventos de orientación vocacional donde expliquen en que consisten las ciencias computacionales así como el trabajo de un programador profesional y los recursos que tienen para realizar su labor, donde *obviamente* se hablaría de las comunidades de programadores y Stack Overflow en Español.

Answer (score 1):

## Preparación para la Vida Profesional

Una oportunidad es participar en los programas preparación para la vida profesional que tienen algunas universidades.

Este tipo de programas suelen incluir sugerencias a los estudiantes de participar en actividades extracurriculares que son relevantes a los empleadores, eventos de networking entre estudiantes, graduados y empleadores, redacción de currículum vitae / hoja de vida, ensayos de entrevistas de trabajo, ferias de empleo, entre otras.

Sugiero que los embajadores educacionales se pongan en contacto con las oficinas que coordinan este tipo de eventos, por ejemplo, ofrecer una charla sobre "como consultar a experto en programación, ... y obtener una respuesta de este"

Answer (score 0):

Tenía pensado publicar otra pregunta, en cierto modo relacionada, entré a consultar, leyendo las existentes, si era adecuada y me encontré con esta. De modo que me parece pertinente plantear el asunto:

Si se desea que SOes sea un centro de consulta al que acuda la educación, es necesario que ofrezca respuestas **confiables desde el punto de vista de las buenas prácticas, particularmente de seguridad** y no solamente respuestas al ¿cómo hago tal o cual cosa? Muchísimas respuestas a preguntas relacionadas con carga de archivos, tipos mime, etc., (acabo de revisar una cantidad significativa, casi 100 en los últimos días) ofrecen sugerencias permitiendo que quien consulta abra brechas de seguridad inmensas, que exponga sus BD o sus sistemas de archivo, porque no se corrige su código y se le indica como actuar manteniendo el error, o simplemente proponiéndole como cometer el error de modo que sea eficaz en la autodestrucción.

Si ahora, se piensa usar esos bancos de preguntas para enseñar, **¡urge sanearlas!** O, crear un sistema de categorías que marque preguntas y respuestas como fiables para sitios de producción y otras como simplemente correctas desde el punto de vista del uso de ciertas funcionalidades y aspectos sintácticos.

Ahora bien, con un sistema de preguntas y respuestas saneado, cabe pensar en textos, o en grupos de materiales organizados temáticamente y por nivel de profundidad, acompañados de componentes de tipo tutorial.

Antes de despedirme, quiero felicitarlos por la iniciativa.

Comment: Bienvenido a Meta. En este hilo Juan no está implicando que se use SOes como banco de preguntas para enseñar, eso depende de los "enseñantes". Me parece que el ejercicio de valorar si un publicación es útil sería una actividad muy útil para el proceso de enseñanza-aprendizaje así como hacer lo propio para publicar buenas preguntas y respuestas. Relacionado [Mi respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3532/65) a  [¿De qué manera Stack Overflow en español puede ayudar en la enseñanza técnica de las comunidades rurales?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3530/65).

Comment: Gracias por la orientación, acabo de leer, la pregunta y tu respuesta y llegué a la conclusión de que me falta mucho camino para responder con tanta presición.