# ¿De qué manera Stack Overflow en español puede ayudar en la enseñanza técnica de las comunidades rurales?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange, enseñanza-aprendizaje

En Colombia la población indígena, afrodescendiente y campesina vive en comunidades muy alejadas de los centros poblados y la posibilidad de recibir educación formal es casi nula.

El conjunto de saberes y la gran comunidad que soporta el sitio Stack Overflow en español, presenta una oportunidad única de conocimiento para dichas comunidades, las cuales, gracias a las nuevas tecnologías móviles, pueden acceder al internet.

En este orden de ideas, ¿de qué manera puede ser útil para la población alejada de los centros urbanos esta comunidad?

Además, ¿con qué herramientas se cuenta para satisfacer esta necesidad?

¡Gracias por sus comentarios y respuestas!

Comment: En mi opinión, no es [es.so] la plataforma más adecuada para la enseñanza. Por el formato del sitio (preguntas y respuestas) es muy útil en la resolución de dudas concretas, pero este formato hace que sea complicada su adaptación a tutoriales o articulos técnicos extensos que serían mas adecuados a la enseñanza.

Comment: @Pikoh muchas gracias por tu opinión. Pero teniendo en cuenta el tipo de sitio y su dinámica, quizás exista un índice de materias o ciertos hilos conductores (o en la valoración de las preguntas o de otros usuarios, etc.) que puedan servir con un fin didáctico (en cuanto al aprendizaje de resolución práctica de problemas cotidianos).

Comment: Sebastián ¿a qué formas enseñanza técnica te refieres? ¿Escolarizada, educación continua, auto-aprendizaje, dirigida por campañas / eventos?¿tienes en mente algún programa, entidad educativa en particular? ¿Cuál es tu rol en tales comunidades? ¿Tienen estas comunidades acceso irrestricto a Internet? ¿Participan estas comunidades en proyectos de código abierto?

Comment: @Rubén más que nada me refiero al autoaprendizaje. Sí, efectivamente tengo una entidad en mente para la elaboración de un programa de autoaprendizaje, esa entidad es la ONIC (Organización Nacional Indígena de Colombia). Mi rol ante tales comunidades es de asesor y algunas de las comunidades tienen acceso completo a internet y la idea sería enseñar la importancia del código abierto ya que no hay nada por el estilo, pero si hay muchas personas con muchas habilidades técnicas en informática y electrónica. También me interesa el hardware como Aarduino...

Comment: Sebastián: Los detalles que compartes en el comentario son relevantes para hacer la pregunta más clara y específica. Me parece que sería bueno que los incluyeras en la pregunta, sin embargo, acá en Meta las reglas son un poco más laxas aparte de que ya has aceptado una respuesta por lo que queda en tí editar esta pregunta para incluirlos.

Comment: Vengo a darle las felicitationes por tan humanitaria e innovadora causa Sr @SebastiánContreras. Ojalá sea un proyecto muy fructifero y por lo que plantea está bien estructurado. Imagino entonces quiere enseñar programación de microcontroladores. Si es posible podría incluso utilizar los PIC que son una alternativa más económica a arduino y pueden ser programados en ensamblador y C por ejemplo. Un saludo

Comment: @Huskie Muchas gracias por su apoyo y sí, efectivamente, la idea es trabajar con PIC por el costo y lo difundidos que están en el mercado.

Comment: Le recomiendo (probablemente ya lo sepa) utilizar para realizar el diseño de diagramas digitales, circuitos electrónicos y simular el comportamiento del pic;  el software proteus es bastante preciso y amigable al usuario. Muy recomendado para empezar en el mundo de programación de microcontroladores. Le deseo gran éxito en tan bonita labor!

Comment: Creo que webs como [Khan Academy](https://es.khanacademy.org/), [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) y similares están mejor orientadas para enseñar desde cero cualquier conocimiento relacionado con la programación

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En cuanto a las herramientas, en Stack Overflow no hay herramientas de enseñanza per se, hay herramientas para compartir conocimientos en español:

1. Publicaciones: Preguntas, respuestas wiki de etiquetas
2. Comunicación: Comentarios, chat
3. Socialización: Perfil de usuario
4. Búsqueda/indización/SEO
5. Modelo de Stack Exchange (privilegios basados en reputación, normas de comportamiento, etc.)
6. Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad para promover proyectos de los miembros de la comunidad. Véase [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2017](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/65)

Queda en los "enseñantes" y "aprendientes" el sacar provecho de estas herramientas.

**Preguntas relacionadas**

- [Mentoría y equipos de aprendizaje grupal](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/496/65)
- [Usar el chat como aula para aprender en grupo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/561/65)
- [Video introductorio para SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/899/65)

---

**NOTAS:**

- Recién cree la etiqueta [enseñanza-aprendizaje](/questions/tagged/ense%c3%b1anza-aprendizaje), la agregué a este hilo y agregué la etiqueta [promoción-del-sitio](/questions/tagged/promoci%c3%b3n-del-sitio) para facilitar el encontrar preguntas relacionadas.

Comment: Nótese que todas las preguntas relacionadas que indicas están en estado postergado.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Alguna sugerencia al respecto en particular sobre algo que señalar al OP de esta pregunta?

Comment: Las hice en mi respuesta :)

Comment: @fedorqui No recuerdo que hayas mencionado las preguntas relacionadas ni el hecho de que tengamos hilos con estado postergado... releyendo

Comment: Ah, ¿te refieres a si tengo alguna sugerencia respecto por qué están postergadas esas preguntas? No. Ni tampoco están en el ámbito de acción de esta pregunta. Solamente lo comenté para dar contexto a esas interesantes iniciativas, que lamentablemente están paradas.

Comment: Sí, a eso me refería... bueno acabo de crear la etiqueta "enseñanza-aprendizaje" porque los sinónimos que se me ocurrieron no los encontré. ¿Alguna sugerencia para etiquetar mejor estas preguntas relacionadas?

Comment: La verdad es que estuve pensando un rato cuando la edité y no atiné a añadir más que [meta-tag:stackexchange]. ¡Me parece buena idea tener la que acabas de crear!

Comment: Agregada a este hilo... procediendo con los demás. A la del video introductorio le agregué la etiqueta de promoción del sitio, la de enseñanza-aprendizaje me parece que no es pertinente en particular porque aún no está el video (al menos no se menciona que esté listo, creo)

Comment: Gracias muchachos por la edición. y en especial gracias a @Rubén por todas sus orientaciones y los ejemplos publicados (preguntas relacionadas).

Answer (score 11):

En general, uno tiende a utilizar el sitio ([incluso adictivamente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3523/83)) pensando que ayudará a sus prójimos en el sentido más literal: otra gente como uno, programadores, etc. Eso satisface un montón.

Cuando uno piensa que que nuestras preguntas y respuestas puedan servir para ayudar a gente que vive en lugares tan remotos, la satisfacción coge un nivel superior. Como cuando lees que hay gente en la India (no encuentro la noticia) que se formó durante años a partir de la Wikipedia y piensas *anda, lo mismo leyó algo que escribí yo*, etc.

En fin, que lo que quiero decir es que impresiona levantar la cabeza y ver tanto potencial en lo que escribimos aquí. Por ello, creo que hay distintas maneras con las que conseguir ayudar a la enseñanza.

> En este orden de ideas, ¿de qué manera puede ser útil para la población alejada de los centros urbanos esta comunidad?

- Hacer que las cosas se puedan encontrar fácilmente. Con demasiada frecuencia se tiende a preguntar cosas sin prestar demasiada atención a cómo va a envejecer. Es por ello es hay que enfatizar una y mil veces que [debemos escribir títulos descriptivos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2936/83), debemos etiquetar apropiadamente, debemos ir eliminando comentarios obsoletos (propios y extraños), debemos votar lo que vale la pena. Todo ello no es para nosotros, sino para el que venga después: si se encuentra cosas claras, concisas y ponderadas, le servirá. Si no, se irán a otro sitio.
- Dado que son sobre cosas puntuales (como [comenta Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3530/de-qu%C3%A9-manera-stack-overflow-en-espa%C3%B1ol-puede-ayudar-en-la-ense%C3%B1anza-t%C3%A9cnica-de#comment12579_3530)), es difícil que una pregunta sirva de guía sobre un tema. Ahora bien, se puede compensar esta "carencia" utilizando la wiki de la etiqueta como guía de uso y aprendizaje. Esto implica elegir un listado de preguntas útiles y representativas, páginas de documentación, etc.

> Además, ¿con qué herramientas se cuenta para satisfacer esta necesidad?

Las básicas que pone el sitio a nuestra disposición: preguntar, responder, editar y votar. Esto es más que suficiente para la mayoría de las cosas que queremos hacer.

Comment: Excelente respuesta!